# How is the frequency defined in matlabs lowpass

Tags: matlab, filter, lowpass-filter

In the [documentation on `lowpass`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/lowpass.html) I found this:

> `y = lowpass(x,wpass)` filters the input signal `x` using a lowpass
>   filter with normalized passband frequency `wpass` in units of π
>   rad/sample. `lowpass` uses a minimum-order filter with a stopband
>   attenuation of 60 dB and compensates for the delay introduced by the
>   filter. If `x` is a matrix, the function filters each column
>   independently.
>
> `y = lowpass(x,fpass,fs)` specifies that `x` has been sampled at a
>   rate of `fs` hertz. `fpass` is the passband frequency of the filter in
>   hertz.

But it seems like the second one, `y = lowpass(x,fpass,fs)`, does not really use Hz since it does not filter the frequencies above that goven by `fpass`.

How I can use the first one? How can I calculate the `wpass` if I want a lowpass filter with cutoff frequency `x`? Do I need to do `wpass = x/samplerate`? I'm a little bit confused with those radians.

Answer (score 2):

The normalized cut-off frequency is

```
Wn = fc/(fs/2)
```

where `fc` is the cut-off frequency you want and `fs` is the sampling rate. The 2 has something to do with the *Nyquist-Shannon-theorem* but I don't want any confusion. Note that **the filter never is sharp**. So it won't actually cut off at `fc` but it will damp higher frequencies.

To actually control how sharp the filter is, I recommend design the filter directly:
e.g. [`butter`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) gives you a *Butterworth* filter (or the Bessel filter -- less sharp than *Butterworth* but also better gain at `< fc`, or *Chebyshev* filter, which is much sharper but introduces oscillation in the gain at `< fc`). From my experience, usually a 4th order *Butterworth* filter is applied.

```
[b,a] = butter(4,Wn);
sig_flt = filter(b,a,sig);
```

EDIT: In fact, it is [recommended](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsfmj) to use (as @LuisMendo pointed out)

```
[z,p,k] = butter(4,Wn);
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k); % convert to zero-pole-gain filter parameter
sig_flt = sosfilt(sos,sig);
```

to avoid numerical errors:

> In general, use the [z,p,k] syntax to design IIR filters.

(*Chebyshev* is also an IIR filter)

Comment: For `butter` it's better to avoid using `b,a` output and use `z,p,k` instead, in order to avoid numerical instability issues. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsfmj)

Comment: @LuisMendo thx! I didn't know this. The one thing I learned today =)